# Can django models deal with 'Class-level' attributes?

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models

I am looking to build a django app that somehow handles 'class-level' attributes (via an abstract class?) in a way that they can be inherited if no project-specific equivalent value has been defined explicitly.

Is this something that can be implemented in Django's model? It's clearly a messy hack but I was thinking I could 'hard code' rates of roles in the project class and use `max()` between the two:

## models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    rate_role1=100
    rate_role2=120

class hourly_rates(models.Model):
    project=models.OneToOneField(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    role= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rate= models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
```

**In summary, the functionality I am trying to achieve is:**

When creating a new `project` instance, the hourly rate variables are optional. If they are not provided, then when using hourly rate values to calculate costs, they reference the 'global' hourly rates instead. Conversely, if the new project has hour rates (or *some* hourly rates) defined, then these should be preferentially used over the global rates.

Comment: I'm unable to understand what your question is, exactly. The code doesn't seem to have anything to do with what you are asking about. There's no inheritance or abstract class here. Just a simple one-to-one relation.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. I was trying to define the 'master' values in class Project (`rate_role1`/`rate_role2`). I was thinking at least this way, I would have explicitly defined rates in the database table - and the 'master'  values in the Project entity (not ideal as I would have to update Project attributes as and when new roles are created)

Comment: I still have no idea what problem you are trying to solve. You define the attributes `rate_role1` and `rate_role2`, and the one-to-one relationship between your two models, but I can't understand the purpose of those attributes and that relation. One-to-one relationships have a much narrower use than regular one-to-many (`models.ForeignKey`) relations.

Comment: Hi @HåkenLid - I've updated the question to try and clarify. Thanks in advance